# Bad Request - node js ajax post

Tags: node.js, jquery, express

I'm using express 3.0 and node v0.11.0. I have a button which submits a form and I'm using ajax to post that data as a JSON object to my node server.
The client code is:

```
$('#contact').submit(function(e) {
console.log('submit called');
var formData = JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject());
console.log(formData);

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/savedata/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {objectData: formData},
    contentType: "application/json",
    complete: function() {
      console.log('process complete');
    },
    success: function(data) {
      console.log('process sucess');
    },
    error: function() {
      console.log('process error');
    },
  });
return false;
});
```

Then on my server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', {maxAge: 86400000}));
app.engine('.jade', require('jade').__express);

app.post('/savedata', function(req, res) {
  console.log('savedata called');
  console.log(req.body);
  //var resultObject = JSON.parse(req.body.objectData);
  //console.log(resultObject);
  res.end();
});
```

The problem that I'm facing is that when I use the express.bodyParser() middleware, I get a:

```
Error: Bad Request
at next (/home/captain/data/lemontreecakes/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/proto.js:125:13)
at /home/captain/data/lemontreecakes/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/bodyParser.js:54:23
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/captain/data/lemontreecakes/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/middleware/json.js:74:60)
at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
at _stream_readable.js:883:14
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

This is the console output in my browser:

```
submit called load.js:33
{"name":"tes","email":"tets@est.com"} load.js:36
POST http://localhost:3000/savedata/ 400 (Bad Request) jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5
process error load.js:54
process complete
```

So I know that I'm submitting data to my server.  If I remove the body parser middle ware from node server, then I get

```
savedata called
TypeError: Cannot read property 'objectData' of undefined
```

I'm thinking that I'm not sending JSON data properly to the server. Any hints will be appreciated.

Comment: Do not use `JSON.stringify` on your form data, but pass the serialized form data as `data` parameter directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure if this solves the problem but try this:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: JSON.stringify({ "objectData": formData}),
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you this works.  As Gustav pointed out above I needed to send a strngified JSON object to the server, and since my server is doing a JSON.parse(req.body.objectData), I need to send an objectData.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code instead:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/savedata/",
        type: "POST",
        data: formData,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            alert('success');
        },
        error: function() {
            alert('error');
        }
    }
);
```

- First of all, browser-based AJAX may not do a cross-domain HTTP request (for instance, your website `localhost:3000` may not do an AJAX request to `google.com` or any website other than `localhost:3000`). So if you really want to do this, let your server handle it.

  Otherwise, as 99% of the time, just use a relative URL (`/savedata/`).
- Also, make sure you only send a **stringified JSON Object**, and *not* an JSON Object.

  For example `'{"test" : 1}'` and **not** `{"test" : 1}`. So in your case, the stringified object is formData.

I did try this code with example data on a node server, and it worked fine. If you have any additionnal question, feel free to ask.

I can also give you the code if you want it.

Comment: Thanks mate, now I realise that I have to send a stringified JSON Object.  I do plan to do cross-domain HTTP request with this, I was reading that setting the dataType to 'jsonp' should do the trick.